# How to auto indent the characters of rb, erb, .html.erb files?

Tags: gedit, ruby, rails

In mac using Text - Mate we can easily auto - indent the characters in the file for Ruby on Rails code in various rb,erb or html.erb files. I am searching for a plugin for GEdit for the same purpose after trying hard I am unable to find any suitable plugin which can work for me. Any clues which plugin I should go for and how to get that ?

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: @pl1nk not as if now....and seems there is no plugin for Gedit. Rails plugin is avaialable for eclipse if you want to try that out

Comment: Do this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16357/auto-indentation-in-gedit) and/or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49761/how-can-i-get-gedit-ready-for-programming-in-ruby-and-ruby-on-rails) help?

Comment: the plugins specified in second link adds auto-completion and some other good features but not solves the real solution of aligning text in proper indentation like in **textmate** or other editors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.sublimetext.com/2 seems the best editor to me available for all Operating Systems

Answer (score 2):

In the Preferences menu of gedit navigate to the`Editor` tab, there you can enable automatic indentation (tick the box to activate it).

Comment: which menu u talking about @kosaidpo ??

Comment: up there  near the File menu  ,view ... etc

Comment: it has just file, edit, view, search, tools, documents and help ?? @kosaidpo which one to follow

Comment: under that entry Edit you ll see a sub-menu named preferences click that then you get an interface there you ll find tabs under the second tab read those options you find what you want  good luck ;]

Comment: Yes I have seen that which states smart indentation. I have checked that but that doesn't align the text which i insert later on. If I start writing code it aligns only that. But in case I have already written the code and now I want to Indent it properly how to do that @kosaidpo